# Replace literal * in variable to another value

Tags: bash

I'm trying to replace a literal `*` in a string, with a `$variable`. I have tried these variations:

```
sed "s/*/$domain/g" <<< $exlusion
sed "s/\*/$domain/g" <<< $exlusion
sed "s/\\*/$domain/g" <<< $exlusion
```

I've even tried:

```
$exlusion = sed "s/\\*/$domain/g" <<< $exlusion
```

and

```
exclusion="${exlusion//\\*/$domain}"
```

However, the * never gets replaced. What am I doing wrong? It works fine when I test the same logic in SSH:

```
sed "s/\\*/foo/g" <<< *:public_html
foo:public_html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `sed`. Using shell parameter expansion:

```
exclusion='*:public_html'
domain=foo

echo "${exclusion/\*/$domain}"
```

should work.

Comment: OMG yes that was it - but it was also something else. The script I was editing (not my own), had a typo: `exlusion` ... should have been `exclusion`. My code was doing: `exclusion="${exlusion/\*/$domain}"` (notice the correct spelling in the variable), and then I was printing out the old variable name... DUH! Thanks for getting me on the right tracks :)

Comment: Are the double quotes around $domain needed?

Comment: @choroba No, they are not. I've removed them.